# Custom Report Page

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I use SSRS in SharePoint Integrated mode. I want to add (to SharePoint 2010) custom reports page which displays SSRS reports. User can select (from drop down or menu) which report should be rendered (ajax would be nice but it is not 'must have'). My question is: what is the best approach to implement such page? Should I use ReportViewer Control, SSRS webpart or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly SSRS with sharepoint integrated mode is really very slow and no real solution to it, if this is not a problem for you than do it using ReportViewer control.